# how to substring in javascript with "

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

How can I cut this string:  `{"5"}`, and get only `5`?

Actually I did some sql query in php and echo it with: `echo json_encode($array);`
And this is what I get from the php file: `{"5"}`

Comment: Why don't you just not use `json_encode`?

Comment: Do you *really* get `{"5"}`?  Because that's invalid JSON, which `json_encode` would *never* produce!  How are you *really* echoing it, and what do you *really* get?  If you get valid JSON, then just use `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: Are you asking how to have literal quotes in strings you're passing as parameters to functions? In which case, escape them with \, like this: "\"". But yeah, better, if your input is json, use a json parser, don't try to build your own.

Comment: Considering the tags ... `var v = '{"5"}';`
`v.replace(/\{\"(\d+)\"\}/,"$1");`

Answer (score 0):

If you do this in PHP:

```
<script>
    var x = <? echo json_encode(array("5")); ?>; 
    // response
    // var x = ["5"];
    alert(x[0]);
</script>
```

Or this:

```
<script>
    var x = <? echo "5"; ?>;
    // response
    // var x = "5";
    alert(x);
</script>
```